# LoadRunner code error

Tags: c#, loadrunner

I'm new to C#. Generated some code using LoadRunner and getting many errors. Here are couple and appreciate any help on how to resolve this?

**System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IList' could be found**

```
        //#warning:  Code Generation Error
        // Found an undefined object of type System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection. Assigning it the name EntityConnection_1.
        // Suggested solution: adding both this type, in assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, to the filter 
        // and/or any other types that return instances of this one.
        // Note:  This script will not compile as is.
        lr.log("Event 31720: EntityConnection_1.BeginTransaction();");
        DbTransaction_1 = EntityConnection_1.BeginTransaction();
```

Thanks in advance

Nick

Comment: The file is large. Here is part of the code.

Comment: // Note:  This script will not compile as is.
   lr.log("Event 31720: EntityConnection_1.BeginTransaction();");
   DbTransaction_1 = EntityConnection_1.BeginTransaction();

   lr.log("Event 31721: new SqlCommand();");
   SqlCommand_91 = new SqlCommand();

   lr.log("Event 31722: new SqlParameter(\"@0\", Decimal.Parse(\"145621\"));");
   SqlParameter_43 = new SqlParameter("@0", Decimal.Parse("145621"));

Comment: Edit it directly to your post